# Firebase get value error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, app-inventor

Afternoon everyone,

I created screen in which the firebase stores the data according to the status of sponsorship (Didn't Approach, Approached +ve,Approched +ve).

[image: Firebase Database]

The project saves the data under **4 different project bucket** which will have a **undefined no of tags** (Sponsor Name) **each containing a list of 3 values**(Name,Branch and Amount)

**User Input in this screen** - Name, Banch, Name of Sponsor, Status of Sponsorship, Amount

[image: Entry Screen Blocks]

The problem arises in the second screen where the entered data is displayed from the firebase.
By default I made it to display the data from ProjectBucket "Got"

Here is the blocks for the screen:

[image: View Screen Blocks]

**The error obtained is:**

```
Runtime Error
The operation insert list item cannot accept the arguments: , [()], [(Arjun M5 1945040)], [(Rockstar (Arjun M5 1945040))]
Note: You will not see another error reported for 5 seconds.
```

Which corresponds to the value in the firebase at ProjectBucked Got

**What I want to do with this screen**

- Have a dropdown list that selects 4 options (4 of the ProjectBucket ie Didn't Approach, Approached +ve,Approched +ve)
- Display the contents from firebase on the screen (**On Labels**-Sponsor Name (Tag of the data), Name,Branch,Amount ). There are going to a **undefined no of subvalues** of each projectbucket (Didn't Approach, Approached +ve,Approched +ve) these subvalues or tags are the **Sponsor Name**, these along with **Name, Branch and Amount have to be displayed for all the entries**

*Thanks for your time*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
The operation insert list item cannot accept the arguments: , [()], [(Arjun M5 1945040)], [(Rockstar (Arjun M5 1945040))]
```

it looks like your global variable Data is an empty string, this should be an empty list...
[image]

if you are working with lists, then the `valueIfTagNotThere` socket should be a **create empty list** block instead of an *empty string* ...

[image]